# Масштабирование QLabel

Tags: qt, c++

При вставке изображения в QLabel оно растягивается по размеру label. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы изображение не растягивалось и размер был не больше размера самой label. Т.е. должен быть эффект Zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt.Урок 2. Масштабирование картинок. Автор: Семен Давыдов 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erIyfptlQ9c

Код на пример из ролика:
https://github.com/offs/geekschool/tree/master/ex2_scaled_pixmap