# Изображение по размеру Lable

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qpixmap

Пытаюсь добавить изображение в элемент `label` методом `QPixmap`, мой код:

```
QPixmap pix;
pix.load("/root/1.png");
ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
int pixW = pix.width();
int labelW =ui->label->width();
double factor = double(labelW)/pixW;
ui->label->setFixedWidth(factor * ui->label->pixmap()->width());
ui->label->setFixedHeight(factor * ui->label->pixmap()->height());
```

Получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само изображение имеет размер `5085×2459 точек`.

Это происходит в случае, когда к `Label` применена какая-либо `компоновка`. Без компоновки картинка отлично помещается в границы `Label` без потери качества.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно загрузить изображение чтобы оно распределялось по границам `Label` без потери качества и при его изменении.

Я пробовал [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-qlabel) и подобные проекты, но изображение очень падает в качестве.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: ещё вот такой пример использовал https://drive.google.com/file/d/15UfR2am2RBTtmVJPbnUe7Ei7ofzUgKA8/view

Comment: чтобы задавать размер лэйбла, надо сайз полиси указывать фиксед, иначе размер будет задаваться компановкой

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, поставил `Fixed` в вертикальной и горизонтальной политике - не помогло.. осталось всё также на своём месте. Кстати, прикрутил сюда функцию:

`void MainWindow::on_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1)
{
ui->label->setFixedWidth(arg1 * ui->label->pixmap()->width());
ui->label->setFixedHeight(arg1 * ui->label->pixmap()->height());
}`

изменяя `SpinBox` - картинка увеличивается и уменьшается без потери качества. как бы вот также сделать но только чтоб отслеживала размер окна.

Comment: не вполне ясно что надо получить то. у вас размер не изменяется или изменяется не так как надо?